# How to dockerize nx monorepo which has a shared package.json on root?

Tags: docker, microservices, nest, monorepo

I have an Nx Monorepo project which includes one frontend-next project, one gateway microservice and four microservices. They are sharing the same package.json. I am struggling with dockerizing them.

My project structure is like this:

```
├── monorepo-folder
|  |--apps
|    ├── frontend-next
|    |    ├── src
|    |    ├── Dockerfile
|    |    ├── tsconfig.build.json
|    |    ├── tsconfig.json
|    ├── api-gateway
|    |    ├── src
|    |    ├── Dockerfile
|    |    ├── tsconfig.build.json
|    |    ├── tsconfig.json
|    ├── user-service
|    |    ├── src
|    |    ├── Dockerfile
|    |    ├── tsconfig.build.json
|    |    ├── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── .dockerignore
├── nx.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── yarn.lock
├── docker-compose.yml
├── .dockerignore
```

Here is an example of the "Dockerfile" inside of each project:

```
# microservice1/Dockerfile
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /monorepo-folder/apps/user-service/

# Install app dependencies
COPY /monorepo-folder/package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I have run `docker-compose build`, and there was a warning about the COPY, but it disappeared too fast, so I couldn't catch it.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    container_name: commerce-postgres-db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: commerce
      POSTGRES_USER: ogeday
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: develop
    volumes:
      - './_datastorage/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.9-management
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.6.0
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: 'my-topic:1:1'
  api-gateway:
    build: ./apps/api-gateway
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
      - kafka
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://my_user:my_password@postgres:5432/my_database
      MESSAGE_BROKER_URL: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      EVENT_BUS_URL: kafka:9092
  product-service:
    build: ./apps/product-service
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
      - kafka
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://my_user:my_password@postgres:5432/my_database
      MESSAGE_BROKER_URL: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      EVENT_BUS_URL: kafka:9092
  user-service:
    build: ./apps/user-service/
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
      - kafka
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://my_user:my_password@postgres:5432/my_database
      MESSAGE_BROKER_URL: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      EVENT_BUS_URL: kafka:9092
  order-service:
    build: ./apps/order-service/
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
      - kafka
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://my_user:my_password@postgres:5432/my_database
      MESSAGE_BROKER_URL: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      EVENT_BUS_URL: kafka:9092
  communication-engine:
    build: ./apps/communication-engine/
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - rabbitmq
      - kafka
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://my_user:my_password@postgres:5432/my_database
      MESSAGE_BROKER_URL: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      EVENT_BUS_URL: kafka:9092
  frontend:
    build: ./apps/frontend-next/
    depends_on:
      - api-gateway
      - product-service
      - user-service
      - order-service
      - communication-engine
    ports:
      - '4200:4200'
    environment:
      API_URL: http://localhost:4200
      MESSAGE_BROKER_URL: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
      EVENT_BUS_URL: kafka:9092
volumes:
  my-database:
```

I have run `docker-compose up`, and I got this error:

```
commerce-workspace-order-service-1         | npm ERR! code ENOENT
commerce-workspace-order-service-1         | npm ERR! syscall open
commerce-workspace-communication-engine-1  | npm ERR! code ENOENT
commerce-workspace-communication-engine-1  | npm ERR! syscall open
commerce-workspace-product-service-1       | npm ERR! code ENOENT
commerce-workspace-communication-engine-1  | npm ERR! path /commerce-apps/communication-engine/package.json
commerce-workspace-api-gateway-1           | npm ERR! code ENOENT
commerce-workspace-communication-engine-1  | npm ERR! errno -2
commerce-workspace-order-service-1         | npm ERR! path /commerce-workspace/apps/order-service/package.json
commerce-workspace-api-gateway-1           | npm ERR! syscall open
commerce-workspace-api-gateway-1           | npm ERR! path /commerce-workspace/apps/api-gateway/package.json
commerce-workspace-order-service-1         | npm ERR! errno -2
commerce-workspace-user-service-1          | npm ERR! code ENOENT
commerce-workspace-user-service-1          | npm ERR! syscall open
commerce-workspace-user-service-1          | npm ERR! path /commerce-workspace/apps/user-service/package.json
commerce-workspace-api-gateway-1           | npm ERR! errno -2
commerce-workspace-product-service-1       | npm ERR! syscall open
commerce-workspace-user-service-1          | npm ERR! errno -2
commerce-workspace-product-service-1       | npm ERR! path /commerce-workspace/apps/product-service/package.json
commerce-workspace-product-service-1       | npm ERR! errno -2
commerce-workspace-communication-engine-1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/commerce-workspace/apps/communication-engine/package.json'
commerce-workspace-api-gateway-1           | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/commerce-workspace/apps/api-gateway/package.json'
commerce-workspace-api-gateway-1           | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

I understand that COPY is not working correctly.
Any idea or suggestion would be nice to solve that issue.
Thank you!